# ns3 - using a data quota instead of a time limit to stop a simulated application?

Tags: ns-3

I am using ns-3 to simulate a scenario where the N nodes are sending a predetermined amount of data to a parent node using TCP. I see in the code examples that you can set the Start and Stop time easily.  I am wondering if I could just as easily in a somewhat high-levely way set the amount of data the application needs to transfer before completion and just have it stop once it's done.

I know that I can use `MaxPackets` to limit packet count but I'm not sure if it will take into account retransmits. What I really want to limit isn't retransmits, just the total amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

The BulkSendApplication class is exactly suitable for this purpose.
It could be set up with the BulkSendHelper.

http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen-release/classns3_1_1_bulk_send_application.html